# Poisson Distribution. How to calculate Lamda?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The problem said: Mr. Yul B. Next, owns a candy store. He has stocked up on $3000$ packages of Candy Corn, $1000$ packages of Licorice and $1000$ Chocolate Bars. He lets each one of our $5$ friends pick a piece of candy at random from his stock. Let $X$ be the number of friends who get Candy Corn.

I need to find the distribution of $X$. 
I tougth:

\begin{array}{l|l}
3000 & \text{Candy Corn}\\
1000 & \text{Licorice}\\
1000 & \text{Chocolate Bars}\\
\hline
5000 & \text{Total}\\
\end{array}

$X$ is a Poisson Distribution, with:

Range of $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$

$\lambda = E[X]$, expected value of $X$, $\lambda = np = 5\cdot \frac{3000}{5000} =3$ ??

**Is my answer correct correct? My class mate said that is $\frac{1}{5}$ but we don't no by sure**

Thanks!

Comment: See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to write math using mathjax/latex on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly a [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution). Let $X$ be the random variable that expresses the number of chosen Candy Corn packages. Then it holds:
$$\Pr(X=k) = \dfrac{\dbinom{3000}{k}\cdot \dbinom{2000}{5-k}}{\dbinom{5000}{5}},\quad k = 0, \ldots, 5.$$